exclude log for a specific custom exception type in wildfly/jboss
I want to exclude a custom exception type in JBOSS 8/WILDFLY 28, how to do that?
I add following in my standalone-full.xml in wildfly\standalone\configuration
<logger category="package1.exception.SilentException">
      <level name="OFF"/>
</logger>

Then in java I create an custom Exception called SilentException in package1.exception.
Then in another class I throw an instance of this SilentException, but the SilentException stacktrace is still logged.
Class A{
    public void method1(){
         ...... 
         throw new SilentException();
    }
}


Logger names are derived from Logger.getLogger(name). In a lot of cases, the class name is passed, but that is not required. If you want to disable a specific exception from being logged you'd need to use a java.util.logging.Filter and define the filter in the subsystem.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/logging_with_jboss_eap#filter_expressions
filter expression can only done on a raw unformatted message, but how to use filter expression to exclude a specific exceptional type in an log category?

Only for built-in filters. You can define a custom filter which could filter messages based on the LogRecord.getCause() for example. Let me know if you'd like an example and I could likely create one.

I see the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78647011/how-to-use-jboss-8-logging-subsystem-filter-expressions. I'll add an example there.
