How to use JBOSS 8 logging subsystem Filter Expressions
The documentation for JBoss EAP 7.4 is here
I want to exclude an specific log when the error message contain the word ArithmeticException, I use filter-spec as follow
<filter-spec value="match(&quot;.+?ArithmeticException.+?&quot;)"/>

and the error message I want to exclude is as follow

timestamp":"2024-06-20T18:22:31.994+08:00","sequence":153,"loggerClassName":"org.apache.commons.logging.impl.JBossLog","loggerName":"org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain","level":"ERROR","message":"HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion
threw exception","threadName":"default
task-1","threadId":286,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"fa6100003269","processName":"Main","processId":22212,"stackTrace":":
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero\r\n\tat

so the match should return true, and the log should be shown, but the actual result is NOT shown.
And if I use filter-spec as below
<filter-spec value="match(&quot;.+?abc.+?&quot;)"/>

the match should return false, and the log is NOT shown also.
that mean
both the filter-spec match return false, why the first one
<filter-spec value="match(&quot;.+?ArithmeticException.+?&quot;)"/>

return false in match?
I double check by using the following filter-spec
<filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;.+?ArithmeticException.+?&quot;))"/>

this time the log is shown, which mean match(...) return false and not(match(...)) return true.

You can't do this with the built-in filters. You need to create a new module with a custom filter. The filter would look something like:
public class ExceptionLogFilter implements Filter {
    private final Lock lock;
    private final Set<String> ignoredExceptions;

    public ExceptionLogFilter() {
        ignoredExceptions = new HashSet<>();
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(final LogRecord record) {
        final Throwable cause = record.getThrown();
        if (cause == null) {
            return true;
        }
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return ignoredExceptions.contains(cause.getClass().getName());
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A list of exceptions to ignore.
     *
     * @return the exceptions to ignore
     */
    public String getIgnoredExceptions() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return String.join(",", ignoredExceptions);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A comma delimited list of class names to ignore if the cause types class name is equal to the class name.
     *
     * @param ignoredExceptions a comma delimited list of class names
     */
    public void setIgnoredExceptions(final String ignoredExceptions) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            this.ignoredExceptions.clear();
            this.ignoredExceptions.addAll(Set.of(ignoredExceptions.split(",")));
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

That would need to exist in it's own library that can be installed as a custom module. You can add the module with a CLI command like:
module add --name=org.wildfly.example.logging --resources=/path/to/logging-filter.jar --dependencies=java.logging

Now that you've got the module created, you need to add the filter. With CLI it would look like:
/subsystem=logging/filter=exceptionFilter:add(module=org.wildfly.example.logging, class=org.wildfly.reproducer.filter.ExceptionLogFilter, properties={ignoredExceptions="java.lang.ArithmeticException,org.wildfly.example.CustomException"})

Then you need to add the filter to a logger or handler. For example:
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=filter-spec, value=exceptionFilter)


sorry but I don't know the CLI command "module add --name=org.wildfly.example.logging --resources=/path/to/logging-filter.jar --dependencies=java.logging', is this finally will change on the standalone-full.xml? can I directly modifiy the standalone-full.xml or through admin console GUI? I need some time to study the concept of module in JBOSS/WildFly, anyway, thanks in advance.

and for built-in filters, is if filter -expression match(...) return true, the message will show in log, if match(...) return false, the message will NOT show in log?
And the filter-spec match(...) expression just compare with message part of the error, not including the stacktrace? JBOSS documentation has not clearly state this.

No, the module add command is CLI only. It simply installs a module, it doesn't modify any configuration.Yes, a true response will log a message and a false response will not. The built-in filters only look at the raw unformatted messaged, not the formatted message.https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/configuration_guide/logging_with_jboss_eap#filter_expressions

To add the module, you can manually create it too. https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/configuration_guide/overview_of_class_loading_and_modules#create_a_custom_module

yes, I see “The built-in filters only look at the raw unformatted messaged, not the formatted message.‘’， but is the "message" means the string returned from throwable.getMessage()? not including string in stacktrace, cause? I even found built-in filter filter-spec failed to filter on the exception message.

The raw unformatted messages does not included the stack trace so it cannot filter on the exception. There is an open issue to create an exception filter, but it's not been done yet.
